# Excel Formula for less than 60 but greater than 30

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, powerquery

My current excel formula is:

```
=IF([DVT Contract End Dates Days Left]<=0,"Expired",IF([DVT Contract End Dates Days Left]<60,"Expiring soon",""))
```

I want to modify it like below :

> Remove any days whose are less than 30 and marked Expiring soon which
>   are more than 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF([DVT Contract End Dates Days Left]<=0,"Expired",IF(AND([DVT Contract End Dates Days Left]>30, [DVT Contract End Dates Days Left]<60),"Expiring soon",""))
```

Comment: @Rush on StackOverflow it's nice to the author if you Accept answers :)